# Make website appear in infobox

Tags: google-search, search-results

I wonder how it's possible to set my website as infobox on google results?
Do I need special meta tags, special structured data?

For example, this website:

[image: clash of clans hack search on Google]

It actually doesn't hold no special meta or anything, it's not in first results, but still it appears there, how is it possible?

Comment: I forget where I read it, but I'm fairly certain this is controlled by Google's algorithms and keyword bombing (or whatever you call it) is the only known way to game it (as demonstrated here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structured data. [This tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/) will show you how to add it to your pages.

You can use Google structured data testing tool to check your pages.

The whole vocabulary is available on schema.org: 
schema for games is at schema.org/Game. 
The examples at the bottom of the schema pages have been helpful to me.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly you're probably looking for **'Google My Business'** – the box that sometimes is shown to the right of the search results? I think your screenshot shows 'just' another instance of the same service – here's a screenshot of the full features 'My Business' box:

[image]

Here is a short inroduction with further information on how to connect your website with that (free) service at google.com :  [Get your business on Google for free](https://www.google.com/intl/en/business/)  (https://www.google.com/intl/en/business/).

Comment: I don't think "Google My Business" is quite what the OP is describing. What the OP is showing is the results box immediately below the search box that often shows definitions and concise answers to certain queries. eg. search for `who is superman` (no quotes).

Comment: oh ok – i was mistaken – and i fear i can't properly reproduce **that** info box 'here'. Maybe google hasn't roled that out 'over here' ? *…strange…*

Comment: I'm looking for infobox for queries like "how to remove a file" or "how to [..]". I didn't found no reference on google blogs or anyting related to SEO.